# run-time object creation in Python

Tags: python

I wish to make a relatively fleeting object in Python. In Javascript, which has a similar internal semantic for object management (a lookup table) you can do the following:

```
/* Hopefully I'm not so out of practice with JS that this would cause an error: */
var not_a_defined_class;
not_a_defined_class.this_property_exists_as_of_this_line = 1
```

In Python, you cannot. The equivalent would be something like the following:

```
not_a_defined_class = object()
not_a_defined_class.__dict__['this_property_exists_as_of_this_line'] = 1
```

Evidently, dot-notation to access a member of a class is syntactic sugar:

```
class DefinedClass(object):
    __init(self):
        self.predefined_property = 2

defined_object = DefinedClass()
defined_object.predefined_property = 5
# Is syntactic sugar for:
defined_object.__dict__['predefined_property'] = 5
# But is read-only
defined_object.undefined_property = 6 # AttributeError
```

My questions then are as follows:

1. Is there a difference between `.__dict__['predefined_property'] = 5` and `.predefined_property = 5`?
2. Is dot-notation read-only outside class definitions (i.e. other than `self.new_property =`)? (As far as I can tell this is the case)
3. If so, why? Type safety?
4. Is there a way I can work around this? Is there a method called by dot-notation that I can recklessly override in my own class, say `MessyObject`?

Of course, I could use a dictionary object to similar effect. I'm really asking this question to learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get an error is that `object` is a Python class defined in C. Those can't be extended. The same is true for other internal / C-based classes like `str` and `list`:

```
 > a = 'x'
 > a.foo = 1
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

But you can extend those classes:

```
>>> class MyString(str): pass
... 
>>> a = MyString()
>>> a.foo = 1
>>> len(a)
0
```

Re #1: For classes defined in Python code: Usually not. There are some corner cases which is why you should use `setattr()` instead.

Re #2 and #3: No. As I said above, this is only true for internal types.

Re #4: See above.